# how to replace string with string

Tags: java, string

i need to replace each second letter in every word with string expression

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     StringBuffer stbf=new StringBuffer("la la la");
     int k=1;
     String a= "wkj" ;
     String s1 = null;
     for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
         stbf.insert(1, a);
     }
     System.out.println(stbf);
```

as a result i want to see lwkj lwkj lwkj

Comment: So what is your code doing now ? and what you are expecting ?

Comment: `stbf=stbf.replaceAll("la", "lwkj");` will do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String input = "la la la";
String replacement = "wkj";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\b(\\w)\\w", "$1"+replacement);
System.out.println("input: " + input);
System.out.println("output: " + output);
```

The regex `\b(\w)\w` will match the first two characters of each word in the sequence, and the replacement uses the first (captured) character, appended to the replacement.

**Output:**

```
la la la
lwkj lwkj lwkj
```

Answer (score 1):

without giving a full solution to the problem, here are some hints:

1. You should split your input string (example was "la la la") into distinct words. Use e.g. String.split(" ").
2. You can then process every single word, keeping the first character, inserting your replacement string (example was "wkj") and appending third and any other character following. To do this, you could use String.substring(0, 1) to obtain the first character and all characters starting by the third character position (String.substring(2)). Have a look at the String api.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```html
String str = "la la la";
String answer = str.replaceAll("a", "wkj");
System.out.println("Replace String Is: " + answer);
```

str.replaceAll("a", "wkj")